# Attach CC0 licensed datasets to own R package

Tags: licensing, cc0, package

I am writing an R package that uses data from other authors (UN Voting). Is there any licensing issue in adding the data directly to the package?

I am not sure whether I can just add this data to the package (surely quote it), or if this is not allowed and I should include an extra command that downloads the data every time from the website (15 mb).

Data is downloaded from this Harvard dataverse [website:](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:1902.1/12379)

Answer (score 2):

The CC0 license allows you to do just about anything you like with that dataset, including distributing it along with your R code in the same package.

As a matter of common curtesy, I would recommend that you add things to the documentation of your package

- A statement that the dataset is licensed separately from the rest of the package under the CC0 license
- A reference to the source of the dataset (they prefer it in the form of a citation) and which version you are including

Comment: Great! Thank you for your fast response. I have also contacted the author and got the permission to freely use the data in the package. All the best!